Using Orbital Optimization VQE
How can I use the OrbitalOptimuzationVQE class in qiskit? I want to find the ground state energy if different molecules using OOVQE but I cannot import the orbital optimization vqe class from qiskit. I believe it is no longer active. Is there any other way I can perform OOVQE to find ground state energies?

The code is still there for OrbitalOptimizationVQE, you have to change it to work with the current qiskit version. https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-aqua/blob/stable/0.8/qiskit/chemistry/algorithms/ground_state_solvers/orbital_optimization_vqe.py

Can take a look at other quantum providers like pennylane as well : https://github.com/frankwswang/Orbital-adapted-VQE-demo
